# while web-scraping looping through each url to make a separate text file for every url data getting error

Tags: python, list, web-scraping

```
`for i in urls:
   text=fetch_text(i)
   listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in text])
   result = re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', listToStr)
   basename = "file_"
   file_name = ["{}_{}.txt".format(basename, j) for j in range(37,151)]
   with open(file_name[i], 'w') as f:    ---->Error 
       f.write(result)`
```

i wrote above code to fetch data through each URL and want to create a separate file for every URL data .but getting an error at "with the open line..for file_name as "list indices must be integers or slices, not str" ...
can someone help me through it?

Comment: `i` is not what you think it is and won't work as a list index.

Comment: your loop should iterate the `file_name` variable and not url. Then you can do  `for fn in file_name:`   and use `fn` in the open instead of `file_name[i]`  (iterating lists by index is not pythonic unless you need the index)

Comment: yes, any suggestions on how I should do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a loop to iterate over `file_name`

Then I changed the iteration variable of `urls` to `url` instead of `i` , since `i` should be used for indexes and here you are directly iterating elements.

Now in your case you have one result for each url, but you generate several files inside each url and you store the same result on them.
This looks wrong, so you should really check the logic of your loops

```
for i, url in enmerate(urls):
   text=fetch_text(url)
   listToStr = ' '.join([str(elem) for elem in text])
   result = re.sub(r'<.*?>', '', listToStr)
   basename = "file_"
   file_name = f"{basename}_{i+37}.txt"
   with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
       f.write(result)
```

Comment: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20b9' in position 959: character maps to <undefined>     ,getting this error after that

Comment: it worked with encoding utf-8,thank you so much.

Comment: hey, it creates multiple files but data from first URLs only. So basically same data in all the files.  why it can be?

Comment: because you have a loop that ranges from 37 to 151 inside the urls loop, so for each url you are creating a ton of files with identical content. Why are you doing this in your code?

Comment: I want to create a separate file for each URL's data.

Comment: then what is this range 37 to 155 that you have? where do this numbers come from?

Comment: I edited my question to added an enumerate to the urls loop and add an offset of 37, so your first filename will have the number 37. If this solution works for you please accept the answer.